# Python for loop error: truth value in series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, series

The error says that the truth value for the series is ambiguous.  The error occurs in line 8.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong in this for loop.  If you would like to see the dataframe, I can post it on GitHub.  Thank you in advance for helping!

```
1) charged_off = 0
2) fully_paid = 0
3) percentages = []
4) index = []
5) 
6) for var in emp_length:
7)     for i in range(0,10):
8)         if loan['emp_length'] == emp_length[i] and loan['loan_status'] == 'Charged Off':
9)            charged_off = +1
10)        else: fully_paid = +1
11)        
12)    percentages.append((charged_off / (charged_off + fully_paid))*100)
13)
14) print(percentages)
```

emp_length variable (list output):
['1 year',
'10+ years',
'2 years',
'3 years',
'4 years',
'5 years',
'6 years',
'7 years',
'8 years',
'9 years',
'< 1 year']

The [error message screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHRPI.png)

loan['loan_status'].unique() output: array(['Fully Paid', 'Charged Off'], dtype=object)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the load variable is a pandas DataFrame and when you do
`loan["emp_lenght"]==emp_length[i]` it will return a series of booleans, aka a mask.

You have to write at least the index (row) you are trying to access

Comment: I think it will return a series of booleans, yes.  How will I write the index row?

Comment: To access index i, you can use `load.iloc[i]` and `loan.iloc[i]["emp_length"]` to access the emp_length value

Comment: Thank you for helping!  I will try that method